# React not using already imported css styles

Tags: css, reactjs

From what I understood, if a component in React already imported the css file, other components do not need to import the same file to re-use already imported css styles.  Somehow, sometimes it works for me but sometimes not.

This time I have a css file with the following styles:

```
.auth-div {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 25rem;
    margin: auto;
}

.auth-form-header {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-align: center;
}

.auth-form-container {
    padding-block-end: 10rem;
    width: 90%;
}

.auth-form-label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.auth-form-input {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0.5rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.auth-form-error {
    margin: 0rem 0rem 0rem 1rem;
    font-style: italic;
    color: red;
}

.auth-footer-div {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 25rem;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    /* margin: 1rem 2rem 1rem 20rem; */
}

.auth-footer-div p {
    margin: 0.6rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.auth-form-image-upload__preview {
    width: 13rem;
    height: 13rem;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.2rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
}

.auth-form-image-upload__preview img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    /* no-repeat scroll 0 0; */
}

.auth-form-btn {
    margin: auto;
    /* no-repeat scroll 0 0; */
}
```

It was imported in one component already but to re-use these styles in another component I had to import again.

Can someone please explain to me why?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: It should work for all the child components. Otherwise not.

Comment: If you have a stylesheet which you want to use in multiple components, you should import it in a common parent component of those child components. If don't have a common parent, you can simply import the stylesheet in `App` component i.e. App.jsx, App.tsx or index.jsx file.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  My 2 components are parallel to each other.  After import the style sheet to App.js, I am able to import it once.